# Unable to identify ephemeral storage on EC2 t2.small instance running on Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create swap memory on an EC2 instance as RAM utilization is quite high.

As per recommendations to do it on ephemeral storage, I am trying to find out which mount point is ephemeral storage?

This is the fstab entry on my instance:

[image: this is the fstab entry on my instance]

[image: df -Th shows this]

Now I need to know which one is ephemeral storage so that I can use it for swap. If any of these is not ephemeral then how can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a `t2.small` instance type.

The T2 instance family **does not have an [Instance Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html)** (also known as *Ephemeral Storage*).

To discover which instance types have Instance Store, see: [Amazon EC2 Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

On that page, you will notice that the T2 instances say **EBS-Only** in the Storage column. If you wish to have an Instance Store, select a different instance type that includes an Instance Store. Alternatively, just use a normal Amazon EBS volume for swap space, since the main reason for using a T2 instance is for cost savings.

Comment: Even better than using an extra volume for swap is to use a swap*file* on a volume you already have, to benefit from the fact that larger EBS volumes perform better than small ones.  A 1 GiB gp2 volume is not much of a performance powerhouse.